# Find occurrences with regex and then only remove first character in matched expression

Tags: r, regex

Surprisingly I haven't found a satisfactory answer to this regex problem. I have the following vector:

```
row1
[1] "AA.8.BB.CCCC" "2017"            "3.166.5"         "3.080.2"         "68"              "162.6"          
[7] "185.223.632.4"           "500.332.1"
```

My end result should look like this:

```
row1
[1] "AA.8.BB.CCCC" "2017"     "3,166.5"         "3,080.2"         "68"              "162.6"          
[7] "185,223,632.4"      "500,332.1"
```

The last period in each of the numeric values is the decimal point and the other periods should be converted to commas. I want this done without affecting the value with letters (`[1]`). I tried the following:

```
gsub("[.]\\d{3}[.]", ",", row1)
```

This regex sort of works but doesn't quite do what I want. Additionally it removes the numbers, which is problematic. Is there a way to find the regex and then only remove the first character and not the entire matched values? If there is a better way of approaching this I welcome those responses as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##HYoxC8IwFIR3f0UNHRIsR/JinllCaR0cXB3fpBYXB6kI/ffxtXdw9x3cXOvSlOZhzTAgYxxxVpnOkA8nrYjAjLSRzx6kxFkjMIHXzglEERwJR93Je0TlYNzu9f3drRG5iDwPIlcR2L6sw/b71jm9q5fuM83vcnO1/gE)

```
gsub("\\G\\d+\\K\\.(?=\\d+(?!$))",",",x,perl=T)
```

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/d3lzCP/4)

<sub>Note: The regex at the URL above is changed to `(?:\G|^)` for display purposes (`\G` matches the start of the string `\A`, but not the start of the line).</sub>

```
\G\d+\K\.(?=\d+(?!$))
```

How it works:

- `\G` asserts position either at the end of the previous match or at the start of the string
- `\d+\K\.` matches a digit one or more times, then resets the match (previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match), then match a dot `.` literally
- `(?=\d+(?!$))` positive lookahead ensuring what follows is one or more digits, but not followed by the end of the line

Comment: This is great! A quick question. Typically when I do a find and replace with regex I'm replacing the value that I identified. After having found the pattern you want to replace, where are you telling regex to only replace the period?

Comment: @otteheng you can capture `(\d+)\.` and replace with the `\1,`, but using `\d+\K\.` allows me to set the replacement to just `,` since `\K` tells the engine to forget what it previously matched. It's a beautiful token that some languages have. Alternatives to this are lookbehinds, but since Perl regex engine doesn't allow variable length lookbehinds `(?<=\d+)`, we can't use that, so `\K` it is :)

Comment: I've needed this functionality before but always ended up frustrated and ended up finding a work around. Glad I decided to reach out this time!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a combination of a lookbehind and a lookahead to match only a dot when what is on the left is a digit and on the right are 3 digits followed by a dot.

You could add `perl = TRUE` using gsub.

In the replacement use a comma.

```
(?<=\d)[.](?=\d{3}[.])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x0KQMK/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/pHnFw0)

Double escaped as noted by [@r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans)

```
(?<=\\d)[.](?=\\d{3}[.])
```

Comment: For use in R, you need to double-escape the codes, so `\d` --> `\\d`.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for noting that!

Comment: This would fail against a string like `AA.8.222.BB` - not sure if it's possible, but just making OP aware.

Comment: @ctwheels That is true, but looking at the desired result `AA.8.BB.CCCC` should not be replaced right? Or did I miss it :)

Comment: @Thefourthbird no, just giving a string sample for which it could fail (no replace)

Comment: @ctwheels Ah, ok! Upvoted your answer. The `\G` is solution is nice.